# 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following file.yaml

```
token:
  local:
    key: "localToken"
  development:
    key: "devToken"
  production:
    key: "prodToken"
```

I load the following and store it as global(typed) variable which work

now, I start my nodejs app with the following :

```
"local": "set NODE_ENV='local' && tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules"
```

so my NODE_ENV is a string, and I want to use it to retrieve the correct config. I have guard etc in case of NODE_ENV is not local/production/development.

Now I try to get the config as follow

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV! in global.config.token){
    global.config.token[process.env.NODE_ENV!].key
}
```

but it return me the following

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ local: { key: string; }; dev:
>   { key: string; }; prod: { key: string; }; }'.   No index signature
>   with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ local: { key:
>   string; }; dev: { key: string; }; prod: { key: string; }; }'

Comment: You need to assert `process.env.NODE_ENV` is of the `'local' | 'development' | 'production'` type. It's also not obvious why you have the exclamation mark there.

Comment: I added this     const env = process.env.NODE_ENV as ( 'local' | 'development' | 'production'); 
    console.log(env, global.config.token[env])

I have no compiler error, but the result is env = 'local' and the token['local'] give undefined where config.token.local do return the correct value

Comment: If `token['local']` returns you `undefined` - it means either it does not have that key defined there or it literally holds the `undefined` value. PS: the `as` operator is evil, you better not lie to the compiler.

Comment: I edited, config.token.local return my key, config.token['local'] return undefined

Comment: If your current problem is different from what you asked originally you better augment the question with the actual details.

Comment: y gonna make new question as the problem is different.

Comment: > `config.token.local !== config.token['local']`  I very strongly doubt this!

Comment: @jcalz I surely do a mistake somewhere but, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133003/cant-find-index-of-object