# can't find index of object

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following code in config.yaml

```
mongodb:
  local:
    host: "mongodb://127.0.0.1"
    databaseName: "testApp"
    port: 27017
  development:
    host:
    databaseName: ""
    port: 27017
  production:
    host:
    databaseName: ""
    port: 27017
```

I start the app with

```
"local": "set NODE_ENV='local' && tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules"
```

I load it in the app

```
global.config = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('config.yaml', 'utf8'));
connect();
```

with a type

```
export interface IConfig {
    mongodb: {
        [key:string]: {
            host: string
            databaseName: string
            port: number
        },
        local: {
            host: string
            databaseName: string
            port: number
        },
        development: {
            host: string
            databaseName: string
            port: number
        },
        production: {
            host: string
            databaseName: string
            port: number
        }
    }
}
```

in the app I then try to access it =>

```
connect() {
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV as ( 'local' | 'development' | 'production');
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV!, global.config.token[process.env.NODE_ENV!], global.config.token.local)
}
```

and here the result [image]

I don't understand why I can't access the parameter with string. In the interface, I added the `[key:string]` but even without it doesn't change anything. I also tried remove the 'local' in the commad when I start the app. The file should be loaded Synchronously, so it's not a delay problem.

Comment: Is it just a quotation mark thing?  `set NODE_ENV=local` and not `set NODE_ENV='local'`?

Comment: I tried already, but no changes

Comment: Can you log `global.config.mongodb["local"]`?  If that works, then your problem is that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not the string `"local"` but something else, like `"'local'"` with quotation marks on it.  I know you say "I tried already" but you should triple check because it just doesn't make any sense that `x["y"]` would be different from `x.y`.

Comment: global.config.mongodb["local"] works, i changed "local": "set NODE_ENV=local && tsnd --respawn app/main.ts --experimental-modules" using NODE_ENV=local and NODE_ENV='local' and also NODE_ENV=`local`

Comment: I know it's something like you said, but this thing is driving me crazy

Comment: ok so I JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) and it turn out that even if I do NODE_ENV='local' or any other stuff with it, it returns me a string with "local " with a space at the end.... now I don't know why this but it's crazy.

Comment: so by doing     let env = process.env.NODE_ENV!
    let e = process.env.NODE_ENV!.substring(0, env.length - 1); it works...

Comment: I think you've got this from here, since this is a typo issue and not something likely to help others, and has nothing to do with TypeScript really.  You can try `.trim()` or something, or ask someone about how to use your shell environment to avoid spaces showing up in environment variables.  Good luck.

Comment: yes will see thank for the help